# Find duplicate char sequences in String by regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have an input string and I want to use regex to check if this string has `=` and `$`, e.g:

Input:

```
name=alice$name=peter$name=angelina
```

Output: `true`

Input:

```
name=alicename=peter$name=angelina
```

Output: `false`

My regex does't work:

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([a-z]*=[0-9]*$])*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("name=rob$name=bob");
```

Comment: Just split string by `$` and check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `.matches()`, you may use

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{Lower}+=\\p{Lower}+(?:\\$\\p{Lower}+=\\p{Lower}+)*"); // With `matches()` to ensure whole string match
```

**Details**

- `\p{Lower}+` - 1+ lowercase letters (use `\p{L}` to match any and `\p{Alpha}` to only match ASCII letters)
- `=` - a `=` char
- `\p{Lower}+` - 1+ lowercase letters
- `(?:\\$\\p{Lower}+=\\p{Lower}+)*` - 0 or more occurrences of:

  - `\$` - a `$` char
  - `\p{Lower}+=\p{Lower}+` - 1+ lowercase letters, `=` and 1+ lowercase letters.

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/SfrXcj):

```
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("name=alice$name=peter$name=angelina", "name=alicename=peter$name=angelina");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{Lower}+=\\p{Lower}+(?:\\$\\p{Lower}+=\\p{Lower}+)*");
for (String str : strs)
    System.out.println("\"" + str + "\" => " + pattern.matcher(str).matches());
```

Output:

```
"name=alice$name=peter$name=angelina" => true
"name=alicename=peter$name=angelina" => false
```

Comment: And when I have also "name=alice&name=" or "=alice&name=bob", how to add empty string in regex?

Comment: @AliceVictoria Then use `*` quantifiers, https://ideone.com/p5mgo2

Answer (score 1):

You have extra `]` and need to escape `$` to use it as a character though you also need to match the last parameter without `$` so use

```
([a-z]*=[a-z0-9]*(\$|$))*
```

• `[a-z]*=` : match a-z zero or more times, match = character

• `[a-z0-9]*(\$|$)`: match a-z and 0-9, zero or more times, followed by either `$` character or end of match.

• `([a-z]*=[a-z0-9]*(\$|$))*`: match zero or more occurences of pairs.

Note: use `+` (one or more matches) instead of `*` for strict matching as:

```
([a-z]+=[a-z0-9]+(\$|$))*
```